# Can´t update only parent, hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hi: I'm new to hibernate and i'm trying to load an order which already exists in the DB, change a field and then update the order but i get stuck on the following exception: "org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException: could not execute statement". (must say i don't change the order's lines)

```
public static void closeOrder(Integer idOrder) {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;

  try
  {         
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Order order = (Order) session.load(Order.class, idOrder);
    order.setDate (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

    session.flush();

    tx.commit();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    if(tx != null)
    {
      tx.rollback();
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    session.close();
  }
}
```

Hibernate mappings:
Order.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.Pojos">
    <class name="Order" table="Order">
        <id name="idOrder" type="int" column="idOrder">
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator"> 
                <param name="sequence_name">Order_SEQ</param>
                <param name="initial_value">1</param>
                <param name="increment_size">1</param> 
                <param name="value_column">CurrentValue</param> 
                <param name="optimizer">hilo</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="date"/>
        <many-to-one name="client" column="idClient" class="Clients"/>
        <list name="orderLines" table="OrderLines">
            <key column="idOrder"/>
            <index column="idx"/>
            <one-to-many class="OrderLines"/>
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

OrderLines.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.Pojos">
    <class name="OrderLines" table="OrderLines">
        <id name="idOrderLine" type="int" column="idOrderLine">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="order" column="idOrder" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Note: when i create a new order, add some lines and save it i got no problem.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You must have executed a query in a SQL tool that also modifies this row, but haven't yet executed `commit` and thus keeps locking the row.

Comment: but where? because that is the only code i've been executing.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your IDE, or some other tool allowing to manually execute queries, opened? Isn't there a previous execution of your app still running, or blocked on  a breakpoint?

Comment: you were right, i opened a session in another process to get the order with hql and i've never closed it. Thanks, with your help i solved the problem.